# Display an array in a label

Tags: arrays, sorting, label

I've been searching for the past 2 hours to little avail. I've used stack many times, but can't seem to find what I need. So here's my question...

I have an array with five objects. I need to display one object at a time from the array in a label, and switch between objects while maintaining the objects' order in the array when the user refreshes the page.

I'm currently using this code, but this code produces random objects in the label. The owner wants the objects in their specific order in the label.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];

uint32_t random = arc4random_uniform(5);
 NSString *textString;
 NSArray *textArray;

textArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
             @"one",
             @"two",
             @"three",
             @"four",
             @"five",
             nil];


textString = [textArray objectAtIndex:random];


label.text = textString;
```

In other words, I need the objectAtIndex to be 0 the first time, then 1 the second, 2 the third, etc..., and be looped. Is this possible? I look forward to responses, and possibly kicking myself for an easy solution that I should have thought of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

keep a global variable and assign zero value

```
NSInteger globalVariable = 0
```

and then write a seperate function like below

```
- (Integer) getRandom: (NSArray *)objArray {
   globalVariable +=1

   //reset the globalVariable to starting point.
   if (globalVariable == [objArray count]){ 
      globalVariable = 0;
   }
 return globalVariable;
}
```

something like this ?